# Google web designer | background-image not working

Tags: google-web-designer

I am using google web designer to create an ad. I am trying to use CSS panel to assign a background-image as shown in this picture:

[image]

When I preview the layout or publish and view the file it doesn't show background image because it has messed up with the image name by adding a `_quote_` suffix in file name.

[image]

I have tried to go in code view and remove the quotes but it didn't help. I believe it's a GWD software issue but if there is any work around to this please suggest. (Note: I am using `background-image` because I want to animate the background image by repeating it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution!

Instead of inline style use style tag in code view to assign background.